# Большие изображения в imageview

Tags: android, изображения, android-asynctask

Как можно ускорить загрузку изображения в imageview? я сделал реализацию через asynctask, в самом потоке происходит обработка изображения и вывод его в imageview. но все равно бывает задержка при отображении картинок. сами картинки в формате jpg, разрешение порядка 3000х3000. а сами imageview находятся на viewpager, то есть на каждой его странице новые изображения и при быстрой прокрутке бывает задержка порядка 2-3 секунд до отображения изображения. с маленькими картинками таких проблем не возникает. была идея удалять лишние asynctask, которые не нужны, то есть мне нужно загружать изображения только на 3 страницы viewpager, но при быстрой прокрутке asynctask накапливаются для каждой страницы и естественно приложение от этого работает медленнее. есть какие нибудь идеи по этому поводу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не изобретайте велосипед и возьмите [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) - там все эти вопросы решены.

Comment: Хорошее решение, но все равно не поспевает загружать картинки. Но грузит в разы быстрее, чем моя реализация

Comment: @makavelka понимаете, лучше чем данная библиотека, которая поддерживается и включает в себя, например, LRU-кеш в памяти и на диске(читай карте памяти) с уменьшением картинки через BitmapOptions и прочими отработанными штуками вы все равно не сделаете. А что не поспевает: быть может интернет у Вас слабый?

Comment: Дело не в интернете, я их с карты памяти считываю